# SVG Pie Graph: How to draw irregular sized Pie Graphs

Tags: html, svg

I am attempting to create a SVG Pie Graph that is 277 degrees. **I have some code that creates a pie graph that looks correct but I am unsure if my code is firstly correct(in the correct positions) & whether I could improve it.**

On the left is the pie graph I am attempting to recreate, on the right is my code output:
[image]
[image]

I have a feeling that my attempt has a central point that is too far to the right(where the 2 lines meet). The circle is meant to be 277 degrees. Is my code correct & if not what how can it be fixed - what do I need to change & to what values?

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <path d="M200,200 h-150,-20 a150,150 0 1,0 150,-150 z"
     fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

*PS: Is it possible to just give a degree value for an SVG, because it would be much easier to just say "fill to 277 degrees" instead of using trig for the actual points etc.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Correct path (run to see result)

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" id='pie'>
    <path d="M200,200 L187,100 A100,100 1 1,1 100,200 z"
     fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to offer an alternative to some of the "arc" and "pie chart" answers. You can draw an easy arc and then rotate it into position (in degrees). No calculating coordinates. No plugin or utility.

In my example, I am creating a whole pie. So first a created the biggest piece as a circle. Next create simple 90 degree arcs as the other pie segments. Transform and rotate the arcs to cut off the previous piece. Finally, create a piece to cut off the last (smallest) piece.

In this example, I intentionally left the yellow segemnt short to allow the red circle to show through. I could have easily added a second quarter pie or drawn yellow as a half pie (since it was greater than 90 degrees). Also, if the first piece is smaller than 90 degrees, you could pre calculate the last cover piece to be smaller than the first piece. When drawing pie charts, I feel I would always have a large piece I can sort to be first.

In your case, I could see this as two half pie pieces. One is left in place the other is rotated to whichever angle you need.

I hope this is useful.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
  <title>Create Pie Chart</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    svg {
      display:block; border:2px solid #00c; position:relative;
      top:0%; left:0%; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff;
    }
  </style>

</head><body>

<svg width="12cm" height="5.25cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

<circle cx="300" cy="200" r="150" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />

<path id= "a1" d="M300,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" transform="rotate(180 300 200)"/>
<path id= "a2" d="M300,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" transform="rotate(220 300 200)"/>
<path id= "a3" d="M300,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" transform="rotate(237 300 200)"/>
<path id= "a4" d="M300,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="maroon" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" transform="rotate(320 300 200)"/>
<path id= "a5" d="M300,200 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="red" transform="rotate(400 300 200)"/>

</svg>

<script>

c = 360;

c -= 160;
 document.getElementById('a1').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + c + " 300 200)");

c -= 100;
 document.getElementById('a2').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + c + " 300 200)");

c -= 50;
 document.getElementById('a3').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + c + " 300 200)");

c -= 30;
 document.getElementById('a4').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + c + " 300 200)");

c -= 20;
 document.getElementById('a5').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + c + " 300 200)");

</script>
</body></html>
```